# User Login Youtube API v3

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I have a question.

Is it always neccesary a client login? I am developing an app that shows the captions in a video of my own that is in youtube, but who wants to watch the video need to login. Is there any way to omit this login?

I have the following code: 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests.

but the api call is different.

This app is for show educational videos with caption. Like the edx videos.

Comment: This is your app who needs an api key, not the users.

Comment: yes, but exist a way to not login for download the caption?